# JSON.Stringify with intendation

Tags: javascript

how to format a stringified json object ?

```
JSON.stringify({a: 'avalue', b: 'bvalue'});
```

To output this :

```
{
    a: 'valuea',
    b: 'valueb'
}
```

instead of this :

```
{a:'valuea', b: 'valueb'}
```

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950375/javascript-object-to-formatted-string/12951419#12951419)

Comment: Wouldn't reading the docs for `JSON.stringify` normally be the first step? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: [`[javascript] json indentation`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+json+indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` function takes 3 [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters). The third one defines how many spaces will be inserted for indentation. So that you can use it:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 'avalue', b: 'bvalue'}, null, 2);
```

Comment: Thx !, that's what i was looking for :)